# Laravel 4, Behaviour of Paginate

Tags: php, pagination, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to paginate a blog using Laravel 4, i have successfully used `Post::all();` and then passing that as an array back to the controller. 
My problem is that in my controller i call a model function which goes through the array and parses custom tags to html tags which looks like this:

```
public static function parseContent($content)
    {

    $find    = array('~\[image="(https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))"\](.*?)\[/image\]~s');
    $replace = array('<div class="asset"><img src="$1" alt="$3" class="image" /></div>');
    return   preg_replace($find, $replace, $content);

    }
```

So i tried just adding `->paginate(1);` to `Post::All()` which didn't work so i tried `Post::where('content', '!=', '')->paginate(1);` which seems to work, now `->ToArray();` stopped working and i get the error `"Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator has no effect"`

My question is why do i get this error? and is the paginate function parsed as an array automatically?

Please, tell me if you need to see more of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was trying to save the content into the array again with `$posts[$post]['content'`] and this was what caused the error, i used `$post->content;` instead and it now works.